# Working between classes in Java

Tags: java, class, methods

I am still struggling with the idea of working with different classes in Java and I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. In the main class here `String field[][]= makeField();` `printPattern(field);` I get an error message. Could anybody please explain to me what I did wrong? Thank you in advance!

```
java.util.Scanner;
//main class
public class Game {
    public static int rows;
    public static int colomn;
    public static String name;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
        //name= in.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of rows:");
        rows=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of colomns:");
        colomn=in.nextInt();
        String field[][]= makeField();*// this is where I get the error from eclipse*
        printPattern(field);**
    }
}

public class playingField extends Game{
    //creates an empty field
    public String [][] makeField(){
        String [][]field= new String[rows+1][colomn];
        for (int i=0; i<rows+1; i++) { 
           for (int j=0; j<colomn; j++) {
              if (i==0)
              {
                 field[i][j]=" "+(j+1);
              } else {
                  field[i][j]="|_";
                }
              if (i!=0 && j==colomn-1) { 
                 field[i][j]="|";
              }
           }
        }
        return field;
     }

//print pattern
public static void printField(String [][] field) {
   for (int i=0; i<rows+1; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<colomn; j++) {
         System.out.print (field [i][j]);
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the error, specifically?

Comment: Generally, you should use uppercase for the first letter of a class - it's a style thing.

Comment: Thank you for your responses and tips- I am still pretty new to programming. The error message says "The method makefield() is unidentified for the type Game"

Comment: I also get the same error message for printPattern(field)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two methods from `PlayingField` class.

Method `makeField()` is a `non-static` method and requires an **instance** of `PlayingField` class to run against.

```
    PlayingField pf = new PlayingField;
    String field[][]= pf.makeField();
```

Method `printField()` is declared as `static` so it does not require an instance of  `PlayingField` class to run (though you can use it with the instance as well.

```
    PlayingField.printField(field);
```

or (using already existing instance)

```
    pf.printField(field);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Game` does not have a `makeField()` method. You need to referenc the `playingField` class to use the method. Same with `printPattern()`

```
String field[][] = playingField.makeField();
                       ^^              
playingField.printPattern(field);*
```

Note: Please follow Java naming conventions and use uppercase letters for first letter of a class

**Edit:** `makeField()` not `static`

- You need to instantiate `playingField` to use the method `makeField`
- There is not `printPattern` method. Maybe you wanted `printField(field)`, which also mu st be referenced from the `playerField` class.

Try this:

```
playingField field = new playingFiled()
String field[][] = field.makeField();
palyingField.printField(field);
```

Comment: `makeField()` method is **not** `static`. You cannot use it in a static manner.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `makeField()` is not static, while `printPattern()` is static.. Also you should rename `playingField` to `PlayingField`. But, as is, you could try

```
 String field[][]= new playingField().makeField(); // construct a playingField instance
 playingField.printPattern(field); // use a static method from the playingField class
```